# MSAccess subdatasheet

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have an Access query, listing invoices and related items in subdatasheet:

```
SELECT DISTINCTROW OutgoingInvoice.InvoiceID, OutgoingInvoice.Sum, OutgoingInvoice.Complete, Sum(Products.IncomingSUM) AS [Sum Of Products_SUM], [OutgoingInvoice].[Sum]-[Sum Of Products_SUM] AS Különbözet, OutgoingInvoice.Note, OutgoingInvoice.ID
FROM OutgoingInvoice INNER JOIN Products ON OutgoingInvoice.[ID] = Products.[OutgoingInvoice]
GROUP BY OutgoingInvoice.InvoiceID, OutgoingInvoice.Sum, OutgoingInvoice.Complete, OutgoingInvoice.Note, OutgoingInvoice.ID;
```

The problem, that invoices without items not shown:
[image]
How can I manage to display all the rows from OutgoingInvoice (even if they do not have joined subitem)

Comment: Using `DISTINCT` with a `GROUP BY` always infers you have a problem with your aggregation. `GROUP BY` will already provide a row for each distinct group, so the `DISTINCT` *should* be redundant unless your `GROUP BY` is wrong.

Comment: Use LEFT or RIGHT JOIN, not INNER.

Comment: ms-access doesn't use T-SQL.

Comment: Thank you for your help! The query generated by access, but I removed DISTINTROW. And of course LEFT join is the solution, thank you!

1 more question: I can only edit the fileds in subdatasheet. Is it possible to edit the main query fields too? (Error message: "This recordset is not updateable")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT OutgoingInvoice.InvoiceID,
       OutgoingInvoice.Sum,
       OutgoingInvoice.Complete,
       Sum(Products.IncomingSUM) AS [Sum Of Products_SUM],
       [OutgoingInvoice].[Sum]-[Sum Of Products_SUM] AS Különbözet,
       OutgoingInvoice.Note,
       OutgoingInvoice.ID
FROM OutgoingInvoice
LEFT JOIN Products ON OutgoingInvoice.[ID] = Products.[OutgoingInvoice]
GROUP BY OutgoingInvoice.InvoiceID,
         OutgoingInvoice.Sum,
         OutgoingInvoice.Complete,
         OutgoingInvoice.Note,
         OutgoingInvoice.ID;
```